# Obtener ID desde SQL a ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, relaciones

soy nueva en el mundo de ASP.NET y tengo un problema, deseo obtener el id de una entidad para insertarla en otra que esta relacionada. pero al querer obtener el id tengo un error. Mi proyecto lo tengo dividido en capas en la capa.

Mi capa de datos:

```
public class AntecedentesCD
{
    public void Agregar(antecedentes antec)
    {
        using (var db = new TopicoContext())
        {
            db.antecedentes.Add(antec);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }


    public int UltimoRegistro()
    {
        using (var db = new TopicoContext())
        {
            var LastRecord = (from c in db.atencion
                              orderby c.atencion_id descending
                              select c.atencion_id).First();
            return LastRecord;
        }

    }
}
```

Mi capa de negocio:

```
public class AntecedentesCR
{
    private static readonly AntecedentesCD obj = new AntecedentesCD();

    public static void Agregar(antecedentes antec)
    {
       obj.Agregar(antec);
    }

    public static int UltimoRegistro()
    {
       return obj.UltimoRegistro();
    }
}
```

Mi conrolador:

```
    public ActionResult RegistroAntecedentes()
    {
        return PartialView(AntecedentesCR.UltimoRegistro());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public PartialViewResult RegistroAntecedentes(antecedentes antec)
    {

        try
        {
            AntecedentesCR.Agregar(antec);
            //return Json(new { ok = true, toRedirect = Url.Action("Index") }, 
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return PartialView("RegistroExamC");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //return Json(new { ok = false, msg = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Ocurrió un error al agregar los antecedentes");
            return PartialView();
        }

    }
```

Mi vista parcial:

```
     <!-- Input oculto del id atencion para registrar los antecedentes-->
     <input type="hidden" name="ant_atencion_id" id="" value="idatencion" 
      readonly="readonly" />
```

Pero me esta arrojando el siguiente error al ejecutar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me podrian orientar se los agradeceria, o como poder obtener el ultimo id de una entidad para relacionarlo con otra.

Comment: Agrega el código de la vista `RegistroAntecedentes`, parece que tiene definido un modelo de tipo `AtencionMedicaCE`. Y le estás pasando un entero.

Comment: Gracias, si estoy intentando pasar a esa vista un entero. Lo he intentado por jsonresult y aun así no logro traerme el ID requerido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar el problema del modelo usa el ViewBag para poner ahí el id del último registro:

```
public ActionResult RegistroAntecedentes()
    {
        ViewBag.idUltimoRegistro = AntecedentesCR.UltimoRegistro();
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Y en la vista lo recuperas así:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ant_atencion_id" id="" value="@ViewBag.idUltimoRegistro" 
      readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, al parecer no estoy haciendo bien el llamado del ultimo ID registrado porque me retorna un valor nulo  ViewBag.idUltimoRegistro.

Answer (score 0):

Scarlet. Bienvenida al sitio. Sé que ya elegiste una respuesta, pero espero esta también te ayude.

Hay varios detalles que afinar aquí:

### 1. Obtener el último Id

Cuando guardas un objeto a través de Entity Framework, utilizando el método `SaveChanges()`, el/los objetos guardados exitosamente ya retornan con el Id asignado por el motor de base de datos. Cuando tu haces:

```
using (var db = new TopicoContext())
    {
        db.antecedentes.Add(antec);
        db.SaveChanges(); //
    }
```

al llamar `SaveChanges`, `antec` vuelve con un `antecedente_id` que puedes utilizar luego.

Si quieres utilizar ese Id para

### 2. Guardar una entidad relacionada

Entonces, puedes tomarlo de ahí. Sin embargo, Entity Framework te facilita enormemente la vida y lleva un tracking the las entidades y sub entidades que tú deseas guardar.

Si suponemos que tu entidad `Antecedente`, tiene una propiedad, o un miembro llamado (Por ejemplo) `Seguimiento`, que a su vez tiene un `IdAntecedente`,

```
public class Seguimiento{       
   public string TituloSeguimiento{get;set;}
   public string Descripcion {get;set;}
   public int IDAntecedente {get;set;}
}
```

Si la relación entre antecedente y seguimiento está bien mapeado en la configuración de Entity Framework, puedes hacer algo así

```
public void Agregar(antecedentes antec)
    {
      antec.Seguimiento = 
               new Seguimiento
                 {
                   TituloSeguimiento= "Inicio Seguimiento",
                   DescripcionSeguimiento = "Primer Contacto"  
                 };           
      using (var db = new TopicoContext())
      {
        db.antecedentes.Add(antec);
        db.SaveChanges();
      }
    }
```

Y Entity Framework sabrá que `Seguimiento` es hijo de `Antecedente` y automáticamente asignará el id del antecedente a la propiedad correspondiente de forma automática. De esta manera no tendrás que volver a ir a la base de datos a obtener el Id, porque Entity Framework ya lo obtuvo por ti. Te evitas el [problema N+1](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/07/common-entity-framework-problems-n-1/)

### 3. El controlador y vista

No sé por qué estás devolviendo una vista parcial en lugar de retornar la vista detalles y/o una redirección al `Index`, pero imagino que tienes tus razones.

Al parecer tu vista recibe un modelo del tipo `AtencionMedicaCE` y le estás enviando un `int`. En el controlador, deberás especificar el modelo que estás retornando:

```
return PartialView("RegistroExamC", model);
```

Si quieres que el Id esté disponible en la vista, y ya estás utilizando un modelo, entonces, te convendrá hacer los siguiente.

```
@model AtencionMedicaCE

@Html.HiddenFor(a=> a.IdAtencion)
```

Este método del Html helper renderizará un elemento `<input class="hidden">` para que el Id sea recuperable por medio de javascript y pueda ser enviado en el `POST` si lo tienes dentro de un `form`

Espero esta información te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudo mucho y aclaro muchas dudas que tenia con respecto al tema de relaciones.